# Karatsuba algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, multiplication

So I am implementing Karatsuba's multiplication algorithm in python. Right now I have infinite recursion and cannot figure it out. Any ideas? I will provide more code if needed.

```
  def multiply(self, other):


  # helper function
    def split(largeInt, n):
     least = largeInt._least_significant_digits(n/2)
     most = largeInt._right_shift(n/2)
     if debug: assert least.to_int() + (most.to_int() << (LargeInt.base_bits*(n/2))) == largeInt.to_int()
     return least, most
  n = max(len(str(self)),len(str(other)))
  if (n==1):
     return self.to_int() * other.to_int()
  else:
     aR, aL = split(self,n)
     bR , bL = split(other, n)
     x1 = aL.multiply(bL)
     x2 =aR.multiply(bR)
     a = aL.add(bL)
     b = aR.add(bR)
     x3=a.multiply(b)
  # code for recursive step here
  #return 1 # change this line with your implementation
  return  x1 * 10**n + (x3-x1-x2) * 10**(n/2) + x2
```

Comment: The code has comments like "TODO: your implementation here" and "code for base case here" in it. It also has `return 2` immediately before the actual Karatsuba code. Have you posted the correct code here?

Comment: this code needs to be indented correctly.

Comment: I see you've put some diagnostic print statements in the code. What do they show? What values are being passed into `multiply` once you get deep into the infinite recursion? Are you certain that the large-integer methods you're calling do what you want? Is `n/2` producing an integer or a float, and if the latter is it bad?

Comment: I updated the code, but the print messages printed the same values over and over again, 0 b4294967296 about 20 times then it hit the return statement I put it so it would terminate.

Comment: I figured it out, n = max(len(str(self)),len(str(other))) needed to be  n = max(len(self.digits),len(other.digits)), casting it to a string broke the largeInt class I am using.

Comment: @MartyGriffin: Post your solution as an answer. You can and should answer your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calculating the max length of the number being passed in, doing it this way fixed it.

```
   n = max(len(self.digits),len(other.digits))
```

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- I don't think your values for `a`, `b`, are [what you want them to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).
- A common error is often that split doesn't return strictly smaller numbers : please provide source for `_least_significant_digits`, `_right_shift`.
- What happens when one of your inputs is of length 1, but not the other ? What does split return for the 1-digit number in that case ?